# ImageIcon cannot be set to JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, gridbaglayout, imageicon

I used this procedure in a program to make an array of `JButton`s. The `JButtons` do show up in the frame, but the `ImageIcon` is not put into the buttons. The picture is at the same directory as the program. What is the problem? (space is my frame)

```
static void BasicSetup() {
    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    ImageIcon cell = new ImageIcon("cell.png");

    for (int y = 0; y < 16; y++) {
        count1 = count1 + 1;
        count2 = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
            count2 = count2 + 1;
            field[y][x] = new JButton();
            field[y][x].setIcon(cell);
            constraints.gridx = count1;
            constraints.gridy = count2;
            constraints.weightx = 1;
            jpanel.add(field[y][x], constraints);

        }
    }
    space.add(jpanel);
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner please post a valid [mcve]

Comment: This should work. Can you make sure if "cell.png" really exists the directory from where you are executing this program? For debugging sake, just give the full path for now and then try.

Comment: check the result of `cell.getIconHeight()`, if it is -1 the image was not found/loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see, your error comes due to the way you're reading the image.

In this case I used an image from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209650/example-images-for-code-and-mark-up-qas).

When you pack your app as a JAR file, you'll need to access the images as resources anyway, so, it's better to start accessing them that way right now. In this moment your code is loading the image directly from your filesystem instead of as a resource. You can change it by calling [`ImageIO.read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.net.URL)) method (The linked one is for an URL which I'm using due to linking to an image of the question linked above, but you can read by `File`, `InputStream` or `ImageInputStream` too.

For example:

```
img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("L5DGx.png"));
```

As you're using the same image for each of the buttons (and probably the same size for each button), I recommend you to use [`GridLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) instead of [`GridBagLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).

You can copy-paste this code without modifications, this is called a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://sscce.org/) and next time you should post one similar, so we don't have to write the imports or deduce that `field` is a `JButton` array instead of another `JComponent` (for example a `JTextField` that might better fit the name of `field`)

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ImageIconArray {

    private JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[16][16];
    private JPanel pane;
    private JFrame frame;
    private GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ImageIconArray().createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }

    public void createAndShowGui() {
        BufferedImage img = null;
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5DGx.png");
            img = ImageIO.read(url);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        Icon cell = new ImageIcon(img);
        frame = new JFrame("Example");
        pane = new JPanel();
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(16, 16));

        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
                buttons[i][j] = new JButton();
                buttons[i][j].setIcon(cell);
                constraints.gridx = i;
                constraints.gridy = j;
                constraints.weightx = 1;
                pane.add(buttons[i][j], constraints);

            }
        }
        frame.add(pane);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Here's an output image of what I got when running the above code:

[image]

---

## Additional Tips

1. You're making a `static` method for the creation of the GUI, I suggest you to instead create an instance of your class and call the method that way (w/o the `static` modifier).
2. From the code shown, I deduce that you're not placing your program on the [Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), this might cause you problems due to Threading issues, you can fix it the way I did in the `main` method, calling [`SwingUtilities#invokeLater()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)) method.
3. Your variable naming is confuse, you call `space` to a `JFrame`, if I were you I would call it `frame` or `spaceFrame`. `field` I would call `field` to a `JTextField` not a `JButton` array, I would call that `JButton` array as `buttons` (in plural as it refers to many of them) or `fieldButtons`.
4. Your `for` loops are (in my opinion) inverted, I would start from `x` and then continue to `y` (or do as everyone does and use `i`, `j`, `k` for counter variables in simple loops, or make them have a more descriptive name)
5. You're using `count1` and `count2` variables, which are not necessary, you can have your `constraints.gridx = i;` and `constraints.gridy = j;` (If you prefer using `i` and `j` as your counter variables in your `for` loops as recommended above) or `constraints.gridx = y;` and `constraints.gridy = x;` (if you decide to ignore my tip #4) or `constraints.gridx = x;` and `constraints.gridy = y;` (if you decide to take my tip #4)